# ORA-00904: invalid identifier DBLINK

Tags: oracle, apex

Estoy realizando una consulta desde oracle apex, al momento de realizarla de esta forma `SELECT * FROM stg_ls_empl_cliente@DBL_EXACTUS`

[image: Resultado de la consulta]

El inconveniente que tengo es que al momento de seleccionar un campo en especifico obtengo el error: `ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier`

Query: `SELECT id FROM stg_ls_empl_cliente@DBL_EXACTUS`

[image: Resultado 2]

El DBLINK es creado hacia una base de datos SQL desde oracle, quisiera saber si existe alguna configuración especifica para hacer select de campos especificos.

Comment: Habría que ver cómo está creado el dblink. Base de datos SQL quiere decir SQL Server? Versión de oracle y de sql server, en ese caso? Recuerda [edit] la pregunta y añadir toda esta info faltante. Y pues, no sobra la descripción de la tabla stg_ls_empl_cliente :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error capa 8 pero lo dejo acá por si a alguien mas le sucede.

El error es no colocarle doble comilla al campo seleccionado, al colocarlo de esta forma `SELECT "id" FROM stg_ls_empl_cliente@DBL_EXACTUS` devuelve la información correctamente.

[image: Resultado]